# FieldError when deleting question in django, django-hitcount

Tags: python-3.x, django

I just recently removed my db (sqlite) and migrate everything, so I dont have any data in my tables. I create a superuser and tried to make a question in admin panel, it was OK, then I tried to delete that question and it was Not OK! django gave me this error

> FieldError at /admin/question/question/1/delete/
> Cannot resolve keyword 'object_p' into field. Choices are: content_object, content_type, content_type_id, hit, hit_count_generic_relation, hits, id, modified, object_pk

I'm new to the django and I cant understand what is the problem here! because before it was just fine.

this is the view for delete

```
class QuestionDeletView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "question/question_confirm_delete.html"
    success_url = "/"

    def test_func(self):
        question = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == question.author:
            return True
        return False
```

this is the template for confirmation

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block title %}
   حذف سوال
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section" style="margin: auto; width: fit-content;">
        <br>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group" style=" direction: rtl;">
                <legend style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">حذف سوال</legend>
                <h2>آیا از حذف پست مطمين اید؟</h2>
                <h5>{{ Question.title }}</h5>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-1">حذف</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-1" href="{% url 'question_detail' question.pk %}">برگشت به سوال</a>
        </form>
        <br>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Im using django-hitcount package for managing my user view

```
from hitcount.models import HitCountMixin, HitCount
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class Question(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="پرسنده")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="عنوان پرسش")
    description = RichTextField(verbose_name="متن پرسش")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, allow_unicode=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="تاریخ ایجاد")
    edited_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="تاریخ ویرایش")
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field='object_p', related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="question_like")
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'سوال'
        verbose_name_plural = 'سوال ها'
        ordering = ["-created_date"] 
        db_table = 'Question'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)        
        if not self.slug:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('question_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def likes_count(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

any insight would be helpful.

**UPDATE**
answer:
It was because I missed to type (k) in the "object_pk" and it made it crash! Watch your typing!

Comment: show your model and template (particularly where the form is) please.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I updated the post, I dont have any particular form for deletion, and it was fine before as is!

Comment: @amirmohammadian, what is need of test_func method ???

Comment: @c.grey to check if the request.user is the same user as author to have permission to delete the question? isnt it the reason?

Comment: Show your model, If you have a signal on pre_delete/post_delete show that too.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I guess its not about the form, model or anything in this type, cause the error matches the table names in my djano-hitcount package database tables, like "content_type_id", "hit", "object_pk", ...

Comment: @amirmohammadian just check your models if you haven't written `object_p` instead of `object_pk` somewhere I am quite sure it's something like that, or else you using it some part of QuestionDeleteView which you might not have shown.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat updated, take a look please

Comment: `hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field='object_p', related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')` You can see that you have written `object_p` here replace it with `object_pk`

Answer (score 0):

```
class QuestionDeletView(DeleteView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(QuestionDeletView, self).get_object()
        if self.request.user != question.author:
            raise Http404  # any error you need to display
        return obj
```

For more details read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView)

Comment: Im guessing its about using django-hitcount, because all of this errors are the fields name in my db tables